# Migration on Laravel Moduels

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

how to make migration with specific table ?
I've tried it with the command

```
php artisan module:make-migration alter_table_product_prices_add_supplier_price --table=product_prices Product
```

OR

```
php artisan module:make-migration alter_table_product_prices_add_supplier_price Product --table=product_prices
```

but it's does not work

and how to rollback migration with step on laravel modules ?
I've tried it with the command

```
php artisan module:migrate-rollback --step=1 Product
```

OR

```
php artisan module:migrate-rollback Product --step=1
```

it's also does not work

Comment: When you say Laravel modules do you mean [this](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules)?

Answer (score 1):

if you have already created the table and you want to add/edit/delete a column

you can run this

```
php artisan make:migration add_column_name_to_product_prices_table
```

The important things to note there is

1. **product_prices** is the name of the table,
2. the **to** will tell laravel that you are trying to alter an existing table, so instead of the create method of the **schema**, it will bring the **table** method

This is a screenshot of what I did, and the migration file that laravel created for me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to write module like this --module=your_module.

php artisan module:make-migration add_group_commision_to_supplier_table --module=Supplier --table=suppliers

Comment: The "--module" option does not exist. it's still doesn't work for me

Comment: better to use like php artisan make:migration add_new_column_to_table --path Modules\IDCardBuilders\Database\Migrations\Tenant